# Rewrite my default post URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, htaccess

I want to have this URL structure for my default post type :

```
domain.com/blog/{post_ID}.php
```

For other pages and post, I want a classic URL like :

```
domain.com/page/sub-page/sub-sub-page/...
```

In the permalinks options page, I have this :

[image: permalink options page settings]

It works perfectly for all my pages except for my blog posts where I just want to remove the trailing slash at the end of the URL. How can I do that ? I suppose with htaccess but I don't know how.

Thank you

Comment: It's a client request... in order to maintain SEO. I don't want to fight with him, so I'm just looking for a solution :-)

Comment: In order to mantain SEO it is not a reason in this case. You should pick up a URL format that better represent the resource and it is more useful for readers; the php extension is not the best for a blog post. You should choose a better URL format a set up a 301 redirection from old to new URLto mantain SEO.

Comment: I agree with you, but my question is not about the usefulness of the finality, but rather how to get there

Comment: I know what your question is but you are asking about your intended solution for a problem instead of asking about the actual problem. You said it before, your problem is: "maintain SEO". My comments try to give you the best answer for that problem, not for your intended solution, that is why I use comments and not the answers section. I hope you understand what I mean. I do it with all my best intention.

Comment: I'm not SEO specialized, and I don't wanna be. My client want that kind of URLs, I just want to provide him that kind of URLs. I'm not asking about a SEO advise, I'm just looking for a technical solution for a given problem. Again, I agree with you, I hate that kind of URLs but sincerely, it's real request and I can't say no ! Do you have a technical solution to achieve my request ?

Comment: I've tested setting the permalinks configuration to `/blog/%post_id%.php` and it works as expected. What problem/error do you get exactly? Can you explain what  "it doesn't work" means?

Comment: Yes but others URLs don't have trailing slash. I want only posts ends with .php, other with /
Thanks !